# Partially applied List Comprehension

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm starting to learn Haskell, and it turns out that there, you can make a list comprehension a partially applied function. In other words, it returns a function which accepts a list, and then runs the list comprehension on the list.

Example:

```
boomBangs xs = [ if x < 10 then "BOOM!" else "BANG!" | x <- xs, odd x]

boomBangs can then be called with the actual "xs" argument.
```

My question: is there any way to do this in Python? I've searched around and can't find a way, but I may be missing something.

This would be very valuable to be able to do.

**EDIT:**

There seems to be some confusion over what I meant.

I'd like to be able to define the list comprehension **without having to give it the list to work on** until later.

The idea would be that the list comprehension effectively turns into a function accepting one argument, the list to work on.

E.g. I could do:

```
my_new_func = [x*2 for x in l] # l is **not defined**
```

Then somewhere later in the code:

```
my_new_func(range(10)) # Returns the answer
```

This is a very good functional programming way of doing things.

**Second Edit:**

Here's a way to do what I want, but I wonder if there is a better method:

```
boomBangs = lambda lst: [actual list comprehension]

boomBangs(range(10))
```

Comment: Can't you just make a function which accepts a list and does what you need to do?

Comment: @SukritKalra I'd rather avoid creating a function for this, the idea is for a syntax that makes this easier. See my second edit for thoughts on what you suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately, Python does not provide the kind of list comprehension that you're looking for (and have found in Haskell). Creating a lambda or a function would be the way to go here.

Comment: @EdanMaor why would you "rather avoid creating a function"?

Comment: The Haskell code creates a function. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, `boomBangs xs = ...` is just the Haskell notation for defining a function; e.g. `addOne x = x + 1`. Nothing to do with partial application is going on here.

Comment: D'oh - you're right. I'm still new to Haskell and I just completely missed the fact that this is a normal function definition and thought it was some special list comprehension syntax.

Comment: I wonder - I've never actually seen this used in Python, but it was taught early in a beginner's Haskell tutorial. Is this because it's a more common idiom in Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part that is special about that isn't the list comprehension, it's the function definition. It just so happens that the function returns a list. As such, just define it as a normal function in Python.

```
boomBangs = lambda xs: ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in xs if odd(x)]

def boomBang(xs):
  return ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in xs if odd(x)]
```

And if you need it to be lazy, use a genex instead.

```
boomBangs = lambda xs: ("BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in xs if odd(x))

def boomBang(xs):
  return ("BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in xs if odd(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's list comprehension:

```
xs = ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in range(20) if x % 2 == 1]
```

To incorporate this into a function:

```
def boombang(xs):
    return ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in xs if x % 2 == 1]
```

You could also use `lambda`:

```
>>> boombang = lambda xs: ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in xs if x % 2 == 1]
>>> boombang(range(-10, 20))
['BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!']
>>>
```

List comprehensions work backwards, with the definitions atthe **end**, and the statements at the beginning. At the beginning of this list comprehension, we say `"BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!"`, which translates into:

```
if x < 10:
    xs.append("BOOM!")
else:
    xs.append("BANG!")
```

In the second part, we define x to be each item in the list of numbers 0 to 20, inclusive. After that we make sure that this loop will only complete if x is an odd number, using python's modulo.

---

```
>>> xs = ["BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!" for x in range(20) if x % 2 == 1]
>>> xs
['BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the style you are looking for using the built-in functions `map`, `filter`, and `functools.partial`, but the result may not be very clear or convenient compared to making a Python function as other posters have done.  However, partial application and currying are indeed powerful techniques that can be used in Python.

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

This can be easily demonstrated using the [toolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toolz/) Python package, which contains many functional utilities that are commonly found in other functional programming languages.  `toolz` also has a convenient [curried](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/curry.html) namespace, which I will use to reproduce your examples:

```python
>>> # define our primitive functions for clarity
>>> boombang = lambda x: "BOOM!" if x < 10 else "BANG!"
>>> is_odd = lambda x: x % 2 == 1

>>> # given a list, using built-in functions we can do
>>> map(boombang, filter(is_odd, range(20)))
['BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!']

>>> # if we want to provide the list later, we can do
>>> from toolz.curried import map, filter, compose
>>> boomBangs = compose(map(boombang), filter(is_odd))

>>> # ... Now we have our input list, so let's use it!
>>> list(boomBangs(range(20))
['BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BOOM!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!']
```

Note how we only passed a single argument to `map` and `filter` in the final example.  This is currying!  The functions get called when the final argument is provided, and we did indeed obtain the same result.

Let's use `map` and `filter` separately just to clarify what is going on:

```python
>>> from toolz.curried import map, filter
>>> map_boombang = map(boombang)
>>> list(map_boombang([9, 10, 11]))
['BOOM!', 'BANG!', 'BANG!']

>>> filter_odd = filter(is_odd)
>>> list(filter_odd(range(10)))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```